# images getting rotated in react app

Tags: reactjs, image, react-image

This is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Lightbox from "react-images";
import _1 from "../images/pics/2.jpg";
import _2 from "../images/pics/1.jpg";
import _3 from "../images/pics/3.jpg";
import _4 from "../images/pics/4.jpg";
import _5 from "../images/pics/5.jpg";
import _6 from "../images/pics/6.jpg";
import _7 from "../images/pics/7.jpg";
import _8 from "../images/pics/8.jpg";
import _9 from "../images/pics/9.jpg";

const photos = [
{
    src: _1,
    width: 4,
    height: 3
},
{
    src: _2,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _3,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _4,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _5,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _6,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _7,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _8,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
},
{
    src: _9,
    width: 2,
    height: 2
}
];


class SiteGalleryPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            currentImage: 0,
            lightboxIsOpen: false
        };
    }

    openLightbox = (event, obj) => {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: obj.index,
            lightboxIsOpen: true
        });
    };

    closeLightbox = () => {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: 0,
            lightboxIsOpen: false
        });
    };

    gotoPrevious = () => {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: this.state.currentImage - 1
        });
    };

    gotoNext = () => {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: this.state.currentImage + 1
        });
    };

    render() {
       return (
           <Grid>
                <Grid.Row centered>
                    <Header color="teal" as="h2">
                        Site Gallery
                    </Header>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <div>
                        <Gallery photos={photos} onClick={this.openLightbox} 
/>
                        <Lightbox
                            images={photos}
                            isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
                            onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
                            onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
                            currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
                            onClose={this.closeLightbox}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default SiteGalleryPage;
```

I am using react-images, react-photo-gallery libraries. 
Some of the images are getting rotated when they are visible in the browser.
But they are good when they saved in folder. They are all clicked with a mobile but some of them are only getting rotated.

Please help me how to fix this up!.

Comment: There might be some [Exif data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) in the images that you need to take into consideration.

Comment: @Tholle Can you please explain me what do you mean by that?

Comment: I don't have much experience with image manipulation in React Native, but if some images are unexplainably rotated, it might be because of the Exif data saying it is rotated. I don't know much more than that, sadly.

Comment: It's React only not React Native.

Comment: Ah, my bad. If you use one of the images that gets rotated [with this service](https://www.verexif.com/en/), is the rotation changed?

Comment: Looks like exif has removed but image is still rotating.

Comment: Alright, that's frustrating. Are you sure you saved the image with the one without exif data? Then I don't know what it could be, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think if somehow we get the orientation angle data from exif we maychange it to fix that. Is that possible?